# mariadb dump not able to import

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Everytime i create a dump from our databases and try to import it i get this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 10342: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1
```

The line looks like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 */ /*!50003 TRIGGER `NotDel_Entries` BEFORE DELETE ON `entries_table` FOR EACH ROW SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'table entries_table does not support deletion'; */;;
```

Is this regarding our data or is it just a mariadb issue?

**Version**

mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: How do you create the dump? With mysqldump, mariabackup or your own script?

Comment: Its a script with:

    mysqldump --all-databases --allow-keywords --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data > /tmp/${CURRENT_DATE}data.sql

Comment: Look at the end of your comment the 2 ";;"

Comment: You run on the normal shell or in the mysql>> shell?

Comment: Those are executable comments. I'm not getting that error when running that query directly. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/

Comment: Looks like you hit this bug, open since 2016: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11169 but there doesn't appear to be a resolution or a workaround.

Comment: I'm overthinking my job since I'm working in a company which is using MariaDB. All these MariaDB errors when just trying to copy databases.....this is beyond science.

At the moment i try to migrate all databases from self hosted MariaDB servers to AWS RDS MariaDB in a higher version. There is no single database where you can just make a dump and restore it....even when both servers have the same version there are still syntax errors and stuff.